# Limit of Integration of continuous function

Tags: integral, measure-theory, calculus

How to evaluate the following limit-
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1 f \bigg(\frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{n} \bigg) dx_1 dx_2....dx_n$$.

Here $f()$ is a continuous function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$. Is there any bounds for this integration or this will strictly evaluate to some value?

Comment: One method: use Chebyshev's Inequality to show that when $n$ is large enough, almost all the time the argument of $f$ is close to $1/2.$  It's unclear what you might mean by "any bounds," because you have explicitly given $[0,1]^n$ as the limits of the integral and obviously all these iterated integrals lie between the extremes of $f$ (which are finite because $f$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is compact).

Comment: @whuber can you please explain how to apply Chebyshev's Inequality to prove the argument is close to 1/2.

Comment: Given any $\epsilon\gt 0,$ Chebychev's Inequality assures us that for sufficiently large $n,$ the volume of the region where $|(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)/n-1/2|\le \epsilon$ is very close to $1.$ Assuming $|f|$ is bounded on $[0,1],$ this implies the integral is an average of the values of $f$ within this neighborhood of $1/2$ plus a vanishingly small term. Thus, provided $f$ has a well-defined limiting average value at $1/2$ (which its continuity there assures), the integrals must be approaching that average.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clearly, the integral can be rewritten as $E[f(Y_n)]$, where $Y_n = \frac{1}{n}(X_1 + \cdots + X_n)$, and $X_1, \ldots, X_n \text{ i.i.d.} \sim U(0, 1)$. By (weak) law of large numbers, we have $Y_n \to_d \frac{1}{2}$. This implies, by [portmanteau lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties) for any bounded and continuous function $h$, we have $E[h(Y_n)] \to E[h(1/2)] = h(1/2)$ as $n \to \infty$.

The $f$ in your problem satisfies the boundedness and continuous condition (extend its domain to $\mathbb{R}$ if you want more rigor), so the answer is $f(1/2)$.

---

$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$

As @whuber suggested, there is a non-probabilistic argument, which goes as follows.

For arbitrary given $\eps > 0$, since $f$ is continuous at $1/2$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(1/2)| < \eps$ whenever $|x - 1/2| < \delta$. Also, since $f$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$, there exists $M > 0$ such that $|f| \leq M$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$. (Indeed, from the proof below we can see that the original continuity condition may be weakened to $f$ is continuous at $1/2$ and it is sequentially integrable).

For notational conciseness, for $0 \leq x_1, \ldots, x_n \leq 1$, denote $x_1 + \cdots + x_n$ by $s_n$, the region $[0, 1] \times \cdots \times [0, 1]$ by $V_n$, and the region $\{(x_1, \ldots, x_n): |n^{-1}s_n - 1/2| \geq \delta\}$ by $V_{n,\delta}$. Also denote $dx_1\cdots dx_n$ by $dx$, then
\begin{align*}
 &\left|\int_{V_n} f(n^{-1}s_n) dx - f(1/2)\right| 
\leq \int_{V_n} |f(n^{-1}s_n) dx - f(1/2)| dx \\
=& \int_{V_{n, \delta}} |f(n^{-1}s_n) - f(1/2)| dx + 
\int_{V_{n, \delta}^c} |f(n^{-1}s_n) - f(1/2)| dx \\
<& \int_{V_{n, \delta}} |f(n^{-1}s_n) - f(1/2)| dx + \eps \leq 2M\int_{V_{n, \delta}} dx + \eps. 
\end{align*}
by the setting up. So it remains to show the volume of $V_{n, \delta}$ can be made arbitrarily small when $n$ is sufficiently large.

To this end, Chebyshev's inequality (or repeating its proof essence) implies that
\begin{align*}
& \int_{V_{n, \delta}} dx
\leq \delta^{-2}\int_{V_n}(n^{-1}s_n - 1/2)^2 dx \\
=& \delta^{-2}\int_{V_n}\left(n^{-2}s_n^2 - n^{-1}s_n + \frac{1}{4}\right) dx \\
=& \delta^{-2}\left(n^{-2}\sum_{i = 1}^n \int_{V_n}x_i^2 dx + 2n^{-2}\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}\int_{V_n}x_ix_j dx - n^{-1}\sum_{i = 1}^n\int_{V_n}x_i dx + 
\frac{1}{4}\right) \\
=& \delta^{-2}\left(\frac{1}{3n} + 2n^{-2} \times \frac{n(n - 1)}{2} \times \frac{1}{4} - n^{-1}\times \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{4}\right) \\
=& \frac{1}{12n\delta^2} \to 0
\end{align*}
as $n \to \infty$, and this is what we want to show.

Comment: +1. Notice that you only need $f$ continuous in some neighborhood of $1/2$ and to have a finite absolute integral.

Comment: @whuber Yes, I added a more pure analytical proof to detail your point.